# Rails MySQL has gone away after timeout, catching error and re-executing command automatically for all statements

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have wait_timeout on my MySQL server set to 86400 (24 hours).  I have an application that doesn't get used that often sometimes though (particularly not used on weekends).  So what ends up happening is that on Monday morning, people come in to use the application and each controller has to error once before it works.  This leads to me getting a lot of bug reports because the 'system isn't working'.  It's very frustrating that each controller has to error once in order for rails to reconnect that connection.  Is there a way to catch all of those errors and have it re-execute the statement or do I have to add a check to every controller?

Comment: Doesnt the mysql2 gem automatically open a connection if none are pooled? Ive never seen errors like this.

Comment: I'm using the mysql gem, not the mysql2 gem.  I had some issues with the mysql2 gem when I first tried to use it.

Comment: A monitoring tool to make sure the site is up may work around the issue while providing peace of mind that it is in fact alive.

Comment: What monitoring tool would you recommend?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add `reconnect: true` to `config/database.yml` in the environment you are using so it will automaticly reconnect when a timout occures!

Comment: I have already done this.  It continues to error in the way I described.